# PHP PDO: Sell button for individually rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote some PHP code that shows all 'cars' a user has in his garage. It shows the model, the worth and a sell button, but I can't seem to fix the sell button. The sell button appears in every row in the table together with the model and worth (waarde). **I want that if you press the sell button, the right car gets sold and deleted from the database.** But right now, it doesn't matter which one you press, it sells all the cars. I think I am just putting the code for the selling of the cars at the wrong place, so can someone help me figure this out?

Code:

```
<?php
include "notLoggedIn.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$globalstmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id from users where gebruikersnaam = :username");
$globalstmt->execute(['username' => $username]);
$globalrow = $globalstmt->fetch();
$globalid = $globalrow['id'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT auto_id FROM garage WHERE user_id = :globalid");
$stmt->execute(['globalid' => $globalid]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (count($rows) == 0) {
echo "Je hebt nog geen auto's in je garage.<br /><a href='auto_stelen.php'>Druk hier om een auto te proberen stelen!</a>";
} else {
    echo "<table width='300px''>
    <tr>
        <th>Garage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Model</b></td>
        <td><b>Waarde</b></td>
    </tr>
    <form method='post'>
    ";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $autos = $row['auto_id'];
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM autos WHERE id = :autos");
        $stmt->execute(['autos' => $autos]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
        <td>€" . number_format($row['waarde'], 0, ',', '.') . "</td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='sell' value='Verkopen' /></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "
    </form>
    </table>";
}

if (isset($_POST['sell'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM garage WHERE user_id = :globalid");
    $stmt->execute(['globalid' => $globalid]);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $autos = $row['auto_id'];
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM autos WHERE id = :autos");
        $stmt->execute(['autos' => $autos]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $waarde = $row['waarde'];
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET cashgeld = cashgeld + :waarde WHERE gebruikersnaam = :username");
        $stmt->execute([
            'waarde' => $waarde,
            'username' => $username
        ]);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM garage WHERE auto_id = :autos");
        $stmt->execute(['autos' => $autos]);
        header("Refresh: 0");
    }
}
?>
```

**The page currently looks like this**

[image]

Comment: **Warning!** You're open to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)! Read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn how to use prepared statements correctly, using bound parameters.

Comment: I changed my  code,  better now? @M.Eriksson

Comment: For every button `Verkopen` you have to send the correct values that belong to that sale (=Verkoop).   (P.S. original code got lost in edit.... )

Comment: oops hahaha, posted the right code again

Answer (score 0):

Please, use PDO features. In short, you need to pass the parameter "auto_id".
Now, try this way:

```
<?php

include "notLoggedIn.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$globalstmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id from users where gebruikersnaam = :username");
$globalstmt->execute(['username' => $username]);
$globalrow = $globalstmt->fetch();
$globalid = $globalrow['id'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT auto_id FROM garage WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$stmt->execute(['user_id' => $globalid]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (count($rows) == 0) {
echo "Je hebt nog geen auto's in je garage.<br /><a href='auto_stelen.php'>Druk hier om een auto te proberen stelen!</a>";
} else {
    echo "<table width='300px''>
    <tr>
        <th>Garage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Model</b></td>
        <td><b>Waarde</b></td>
    </tr>
    <form method='post'>
    ";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $autos = $row['auto_id'];
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM autos WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->execute(['id' => $autos]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
        <td>€" . number_format($row['waarde'], 0, ',', '.') . "</td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='sell' value='Verkopen' /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='auto_id' value='".$row['id']."' />";
    }
    echo "
    </form>
    </table>";
}

// New Code for sell button
if (isset($_POST['sell']) && isset($_POST['auto_id'])) {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `autos` WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(['id' => $_POST['auto_id']]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `cashgeld` = `cashgeld` + :waarde WHERE `gebruikersnaam` = :username");
    $stmt->execute([
         'waarde' => $row['waarde'],
         'username' => $username
    ]);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `garage` WHERE `auto_id` = :auto_id");
    $stmt->execute(["auto_id" => $_POST['auto_id']]);

    header("Refresh: 0");

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This just sells the newest one

Answer (score 0):

I would create a seperate form for each Auto in this situation. You also need to be able to know which Auto is being sold so the `auto_id` needs to be part of each form too. Place that into a `hidden` field so it gets passed when the sell button is pressed

To do this move the form into the `<td>` that contains the button.

```
    echo "<table width='300px''>
    <tr>
        <th>Garage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Model</b></td>
        <td><b>Waarde</b></td>
    </tr>";

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $autos = $row['auto_id'];
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM autos WHERE id = :autos");
        $stmt->execute(['autos' => $autos]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$row[model]</td>
            <td>€" . number_format($row['waarde'], 0, ',', '.') . "</td>
            <td>
                <form method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='auto_id` value='$row[id]' />
                    <input type='submit' name='sell' value='Verkopen' />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
```